# c# insert item in order custom linked list

Tags: c#

im trying to add the number 8 into my list using the InsertInOrder method

e.g. my current list 5, 10, 12, 14, 26, 45, 52

after inserting new node 5, 8, 10, 12, 14, 26, 45, 52

i know i have to iterate through the list in order to find the correct position for it 
but where do i start?

```
class LinkList
{

private Link list = null; //default value – empty list

public void AddItem(int item) //add item to front of list
{
    list = new Link(item, list);
}


public void InsertInOrder(int item)
{
    Link temp = list;
    while (temp != null)
    {

        AddItem(item);
        Console.WriteLine(temp.Data);
        temp = temp.Next;

    }
}

public void DisplayItems() // Displays items in list
{
    Link temp = list;
    while (temp != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(temp.Data);
        temp = temp.Next;

    }

}
```

Link class:

```
 class Link
    {
        private int data;
        private Link next;

        public Link(int item) //constructor with an item
        {
            data = item;
            next = null;
        }
        public Link(int item, Link list) //constructor with item and list
        {
            data = item;
            next = list;
        }

        public int Data //property for data
        {
            set { this.data = value; }
            get { return this.data; }
        }

        public Link Next //property for next
        {
            set { this.next = value; }
            get { return this.next; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing homework? InsertInOrder while loop should be good place to start implementing comparison. Also take care of edge cases when inserting as first (value 1) and last element (value 100).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks pretty clean.  I'm not going to post a full solution for you but I will give you a skeleton out line of how you **could** implement `InsertInOrder`.  Note that there are many ways to do this.  All you have to do is fill in the if conditions.

```
public void InsertInOrder(int item)
{
    Link temp = list;
    // check to see if the item goes at the front of the list...
    //   hint : there are 2 conditions where it needs to go in the front.
    if (********* || **********)
    {
        list = new Link(item, list);
    }
    else
    {
        while (temp != null)
        {
            // you have to look at the next item and see if it's bigger
            //  which means it goes next.
            //  if there isn't a next item this item belongs next.
            if (*********** || // there is no next item
                ***********) // this item is bigger than the next item
            {
                temp.Next = new Link(item, temp.Next);
                // we are done so set temp to null so we exit the loop
                temp = null;
            }
            else
            {
                // move on to the next item
                temp = temp.Next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This has been very useful in my implementation, Many thanks for your help